# Ceased Kryptic Klues - Don't Doubt Yourself!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cryptic-clues

[image]

**Horizontal**

2. Great circle's created a torque(9)
4. Red pill, taken in shoots regularly(1)
7. Investigator's flawed, having true instead of false(6)
8. Some organize brave traffic controller from La Paz(8)
9. Best buddy I left after last month(4)
10. Manic yells about random stuff(12)
11. Bite the family cat(3)

**Vertical**

1. Revolting: armpits holding a lunch meat(11)
3. Arson fire damaged last of hot, tropical region(5)
5. Greek underworld, strangely nice.(2)
6. Bangs on back of house leaving returned garments(7)
12. Court attendant heads off to get solder perhaps?(10)

**And Finally**

```
_ _ _ _    _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _!(10)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solutions to individual clues:

Across:

> **2** EQ**U**ATOR *ATORQUE**
>  **4** SOCIA**L**IST *CIALIS in ShOoTs*
>  **7** D**E**TECTIVE *DE(F->T)ECTIVE*
>  **8** ZE**B**RA *substring*
>  **9** ULTIMAT**E** *MATE with I on the left, after ULT*
>  **10** MISCELLAN**Y** *MANICYELLS**
>  **11** MUNCH**K**IN *MUNCH + KIN*

Down:

> **1** PAST**R**AMI *ARMPITS* holding A*
>  **3** RAIN**F**OREST *ARSONFIRE* + (-ho)T*
>  **5** HELLEN**I**C *HELL + NICE**
>  **6** SKI**R**TS *STRIK(-e)S<*
>  **12** **A**LLOY *(-b)ALL (-b)OY*

Here

> the boldfaced letters are the ones (one per clue) that *disagree* with the ones "given" in the diagram.

If we

> fill in answers *leaving the wrong "givens" in place* then each answer in the grid has one incorrect letter, always one of the givens; in two cases it is *also* a correct letter of an intersecting word.

Visually,

> A diagram showing every word highlighting the incorrect letters
>  [image]

Now, the "enumerations"

> are the numbers 1..12 in a random-looking order, so let's rearrange into order of fake-enumeration. The *wrong* "givens" don't seem to say anything useful (nor do they in clue-number order or in clue-appearance order, so I think they are pure red herrings) but the *corrections*, boldfaced in the answers above, Arranging the answers to the clues per the enumerations and replacing *incorrect* letters with **correct** letters.

We get -

> SOCIA*M*IST - **L**
>  HELLEN*O*C - **I**
>  MUNCH*B*IN - **K**
>  ULTIMAT*U* - **E**
>  RAIN*T*OREST - **F**
>  D*O*FECTIVE - **E**
>  SKI*T*TS - **R**
>  ZE*F*RA - **B**
>  E*M*UATOR - **U**
>  *I*LLOY - **A**
>  PAST*E*AMI  - **R**
>  MISCELLAN*E* - **Y**
>
>  **LIKE FERBUARY**

Now

> we can fit those into the "and finally", getting "LIKE FERBUARY! (10)". (Note the deliberate mistake in the second word.) Is this another cryptic clue? No; OP has confirmed in comments that the intended answer is simply **MISSPELLED** because of the misspelled answers per the diagram (though it seems to me that MISPRINTED would work just as well...).

I had no idea what was going on in the title, but in comments OP kindly explained that

> the individual cryptic clues here are all taken from elsewhere: more specifically I think they are all from the ["CCCC" in this site's chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60387050#60387050). So they are *leased* cryptic clues. (Of course each word of "Ceased Kryptic Klues" has a single-letter typo, just like the answers in the crossword itself.)

Comment: Unun . Nf V fnvq, qba'g qbhog lbhefrys Tnergu. ZVFFCRYYRQ vg vf naq nf lbh evtugyl thrffrq sebz gur gvgyr nzq fvapr gur ragver gurzr vf onfrq ba zvffcryyrq jbeqf. Terng wbo!! :)

N ovg bs Gevirn - Gvgyr vf zvffcryyrq sebz "Yrnfrq Pelcgvp Pyhrf" fvapr gur yraqref(frggref) bs gurfr tbbq byq pyhrf, abj erjbeqrq, ner fbzr byq zrzoref sebz GFY. :) V yy or nqqvat gur nggevo fbba. Bapr ntnva, jryy qbar.

Comment: Nyfb, gurer ner ab erq ureevatf. Rirel nafjre unf bar jebat yrggre va gur tevq juvpu jura ercynprq jvgu gur pbeerpg bar tvirf lbh YVXR SREOHNEL juvpu lbh nyernql tbg.